# Переиспользуемые компоненты React

Tags: reactjs

Есть несколько случаев, когда должен использоваться компонент Заявка. Когда я хочу создать новую заявку, я возвращаю один реакт-элемент, а когда я хочу просмотреть уже созданную заявку, я по сути возвращаю тот же элемент, только с небольшими изменениями в верстке. Вопрос - как расширять верстку компонента? Есть вариант передавать флаги компоненту в пропсы, которые описывают в каком контексте он будет использоваться. По флагам компонент решит, какие элементы рендерить. На мой взгляд это неверный подход решения такого вопроса

Answer (score 1):

Например в вашей форме будет использоваться масса разных элементов ввода. Все элементы имеют общую структуру, т.е. у них есть label, у них есть собственно элемент ввода, есть возможность отображения сообщения об ошибке.

Делаете базовый "абстрактный" класс:

```
class InputPlain extends React.Component {
    static propTypes = {
        value: PropTypes.string, // Значение
        placeHolder: PropTypes.string, // Плейсхолдер
        password: PropTypes.bool, // Отображать ли "звездочки" пароля
        disabled: PropTypes.bool, // Элемент не активен
        readOnly: PropTypes.bool, // Элемент рид-онли
        autoComplete: PropTypes.bool, // Разрешать ли автоподстановки
        onChange: PropTypes.func, // Обработчик изменения
        required: PropTypes.bool, // обязательность поля
        error: PropTypes.string, // текст ошибки
        title: PropTypes.string, // Заголовок поля
        helpMessage: PropTypes.string, // подсказка поля
    };

    static defaultProps = {
        password: false,
        disabled: false,
        readOnly: false,
        required: false,
    };

    drawLabel() {
        return (...);
    }
    drawHelpButton(){
        return (...);
    }
    drawInput(){
        return (...);
    }
    drawError(){
        return (...);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.drawLabel()}
                {this.drawHelpButton()}
                {this.drawInput()}
                {this.drawError()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default InputPlain;
```

В соответствующих методах делаете отрисовку стандартных элементов, заголовка подсказки, и т.д. В ваших компонентах будет меняться собственно компонент поля ввода.

Делаем классы-наследники, в которых меняется только метод отрисовки поля ввода:

```
class InputText extends InputPlain {
    drawInput() {
        return (...);
    }
}

class InputDate extends InputPlain {
    drawInput() {
        return (...);
    }
}

class InputTextArea extends InputPlain {
    drawInput() {
        return (...);
    }
}
```

Если вы хотите иметь возможность менять "отрисовку" для элементов, то можно добавить в 'props' поля, для них:

```
static propTypes = {
    ...
    labelNode: PropTupe.node,
    helpNode: PropTupe.node,
    inputNode: PropTupe.node,
    errorNode: PropTupe.node,
};
```

и в соответствующих методах прописать:

```
drawLabel () {
    if(this.props.labelNode) {
        return this.props.labelNode;
    }

    return (...); // стандартная отрисовка
}
```

Тогда будет возможность добавления рендеров отдельных элементов прямо в момент вызова компонента

Answer (score 0):

Если это заявка, то скорее всего у вас используются инпуты для ввода информации, а вывод осуществляется в p, div и т.п. Думаю лучшим вариантом будет сделать новый компонент, т.к. у них будут существенные различия.